# Filter for Nested forms - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-4.2

In my rails application I've two models called 'user' and 'store'. `An user belongs_to store` and `A store has_many users`.An user has many attributes like name,email and role etc.,. In one of the forms for store, I want to use nested forms to create users whose role is **packer** . The Problem is when I use nested forms, other users whose role is not 'packer' are also listed. I specifically want to use nested forms only for users whose role is 'packer'. Is there any way to filter users with role as 'packer' in nested forms

Answer (score 1):

To start with you may want to setup a "short-cut" relationship:

```
class Store < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users
  has_many :packers, -> { where(role: 'packer') }, class_name: 'User'
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :store
end
```

[`fields_for(record_name, record_object = nil, options = {}, &block)`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-fields_for) takes an optional `record_object` argument that lets you set the records used:

```
<%= form_for @store do |f| %>
  ...
  <%= f.fields_for :users, f.object.packers do |user| %>
    <%= user.hidden_field :role %>
    <%= user.text_field :name %>
  <% end %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

Using `f.object` is not strictly necessary - you could use any variable, but it does make it easier to build reusable partials.